# Finding the route display for map in android mobile

Tags: android, mapquest

**What I am doing**::

- I am using **MapQuest** in android for location
- I want to know the route map between two locations
- **What i am using**: [I used this link](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/featured/android-maps-api/documentation)

**What I want**::

- as we can see we are achieving using address as strings .....
- Is it possible to achieve the same below code functionality using
  latitude and longitude passing

---

**Code**::

```
public class MyRouteMap extends MapActivity {
    protected MapView map;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      setupMapView();
      displayRoute();
    }

    // set your map and enable default zoom controls 
    private void setupMapView() {
      this.map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
      map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }

    // create a route and display on the map 
    private void displayRoute() {
      RouteManager routeManager = new RouteManager(this);
      routeManager.setMapView(map);
      routeManager.createRoute("San Francisco, CA", "Fremont, CA");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this example in the mapquest forum http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/255724

routeManager.createRoute("{latLng:{lat:37.765007,lng:-122.239937}}","Fremont, CA");

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass routes as comma delimited lat and lng strings:

```java
routeManager.createRoute("37.765007,-122.239937", "Fremont, CA");
```